# How to setup replica and shard in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

Do you know if there is any web article that can guide me on how to setup replica or shard in ClickHouse? I am not knowledge on ZooKeeper as well, don't know how to get started; most of the article that I read online is about how it works, but I can't find how to setup it.

all these articles do show some settings; however, I don't how to put them together.

For example, I don't know where to put Zoo Keeper configuration...

I read these articles

```
https://clickhouse.yandex/tutorial.html
https://blog.uiza.io/replicated-vs-distributed-on-clickhouse-part-1/
https://blog.uiza.io/replicated-and-distributed-on-clickhouse-part-2/
https://www.altinity.com/blog/2018/5/10/circular-replication-cluster-topology-in-clickhouse
```

```
Set ZooKeeper locations in configuration file
<zookeeper-servers>
    <node>
        <host>zoo01.yandex.ru</host>
        <port>2181</port>
    </node>
    <node>
        <host>zoo02.yandex.ru</host>
        <port>2181</port>
    </node>
    <node>
        <host>zoo03.yandex.ru</host>
        <port>2181</port>
    </node>
</zookeeper-servers>
```

Answer (score 1):

Zookeeper it's a standalone daemon, you need install it and run it (one instance of zookeeper daemon is enough) after that you need add

```
<zookeeper-servers>
    <node>
        <host>zoo01.yourdomain.com</host>
        <port>2181</port>
    </node>
</zookeeper-servers>
```

to config on each Clickhouse server

and add remote-servers configuration to each Clickhouse server, i.e.

```
    <remote_servers>
        <your_cluster_name>
            <shard>
                <weight>1</weight>
                <internal_replication>true</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                    <host>clickhouse-ru-1.local</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                </replica>
                <replica>
                    <host>clickhouse-ru-2.local</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                </replica>
            </shard>
            <shard>
                <weight>1</weight>
                <internal_replication>false</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                    <host>clickhouse-eu-1.local</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                </replica>
                <replica>
                    <host>clickhouse-eu-2.local</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                </replica>
            </shard>
            <shard>
                <weight>1</weight>
                <internal_replication>false</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                    <host>clickhouse-us-1.local</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                </replica>
                <replica>
                    <host>clickhouse-us-2.local</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                </replica>
            </shard>
        </your_cluster_name>
    </remote_servers>
```

after that please read about Distributed table Engine
https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/distributed/

Comment: over the weekend, I learned how to setup Zookeeper cluster in separate set of VM server. Do I need to install any zookeeper components in ClickHouse server?

Comment: Where do I put the about configuration? is it on /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml? some article mentioned about /etc/metrika.xml; however, I can't find this file. This confuse me - how to enable zookeeper for clickhouse

Comment: just setup zookeeper and run zookeeper
and insert ```<remote_servers>...</remote_servers>``` into /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml on each clickhouse node

and insert
```<zookeeper>
        <node index="1">
            <host>zookeeper_host</host>
            <port>2181</port>
        </node>
    </zookeeper>```
on each clickhouse node

Comment: Why only one of the shards have `internal_replication` to true, while the others don't?

Comment: xmar, it's just a test config
for usual replication usage set internal_replication=true for all shards